# Does anyone know where I can find a list of the std:: namespace?? (for C++ 98)

Tags: c++, compilation, namespaces, reserved-words

I want to know which words I shouldn't use as variables after including the using directive. I can't seem to find a list of the namespace :( Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. Google should provide you with several useful results.

Comment: .... other than that, just avoid `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 2):

The most definitive list of all names in the `std` namespace is the C++ Standard.  The current version is over 1300 pages long and probably contains thousands of unique identifiers in `std`.  Beyond that, some compilers might also include some platform-specific identifiers within `std`, and these are largely undocumented -- so you'll have to check the source code for the compiler in question (if even possible), and re-check it again every time they make a patch.

Seem daunting?  Good, so then hopefully I've got your attention.

Don't do `using namespace std` in your code.  **especially** don't `use namespace std` in header files.  Put your identifiers in to their *own* namespaces.  Now you don't have to care what's in whose namespaces.  Call things whatever you want.

I'm all for being lazy, but be smart about it.  If you want to pull in specific names from `std` so you don't have to type `std::` over and over, just pull in those things:

```
using std::string;
```

...and nothing you don't need.  But **only** do this in your CPP files, never in a header.

Comment: you win xD looks like i'll be using std::
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Better idea: Don't use `using namespace std;` in your code. I have never heard of a way to get a listing of everything in the std:: namespace.

Comment: This doesn't answer OPs question

Comment: It's better advice than a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the information presented by John Dibling's answer, I wanted to point out that you don't necessarily have to avoid names in the std namespace even when you do write `using namespace std;`. You can resolve ambiguities in the presence of `using` directives by qualifying names. You can even qualify names in the 'global' namespaces using a top-level `::`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int cout;

int main() {
  ::cout = 10;
}
```

The reason I wanted to point this out is that I know many C++ programmers, even after a few years using it, don't know how to qualify names in the global namespace.